# TypeError: Interaction.delete_original_response() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, pycord

I want to delete massage after 5 seconds

```
@bot.slash_command(name="clearall", description="Clears all Messages")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def clearall(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge()
    await ctx.respond("Done!")
    await discord.Interaction.delete_original_response(delay=5)
@clearall.error
async def clearerror(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.respond("Do you have manage message permissions?")
    else:
        raise error
```

Error:
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: Interaction.delete_original_response() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

await discord.Interaction.delete_original_response(delay=5)
Tried for delete message after it sended by bot

Welp i expected this for work

Answer (score 0):

Should be `await ctx.delete_original_response(delay=5)`.
`ctx` is already an instance of **discord.Interaction**. You're attempting to call the method on the class without creating an instance of that class - but you should just use the `ctx` object.